# How to upload 10 Gb of data to MySQL programmatically without crashing like on PHPMyAdmin?

Tags: mysql

I'm very surprised that it seems impossible to upload more than a few megabytes of data to mysql database through PHPMyAdmin whereas I can upload a msaccess table easily up to 2 Gigabytes.

So is there any script in php or anything that can allow to do so unlike phpmyadmin ?

Comment: Check your MAX_FILE_UPLOAD_SIZE in php.ini isn't set too low.

Comment: @Gazier: Do you really believe that 10GB is a sane value to set it to?

Comment: 10 GB through a browser based file upload. What fun!

Comment: He said to upload more than a few megabytes? Like...a few more megabytes?  EDIT my mistake, misread the question.

Comment: @Gazler it's in the title (Go probably meaning GB in the OP's language).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

PhpMyAdmin is based on HTML and PHP. Both technologies were not built and never intended to handle such amounts of data.

The usual way to go about this would be transferring the file to the remote server - for example using a protocol like (S)FTP, SSH, a Samba share or whatever - and then import it locally using the `mysql` command:

```
mysql -u username -p -h localhost databasename < infile.sql
```

another very fast way to exchange data between two servers with the same mySQL version (it doesn't dump and re-import the data but copies the data directories directly)  is [mysqlhotcopy](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqlhotcopy.html). It runs on Unix/Linux and Netware based servers only, though.

Comment: I need to upload from outside mysql (from text file exported by a datawarehouse db) so I can't use mysqlhotcopy but will be very usefull indeed as I'll have to be able to backup such a huge database later.

Comment: Please Note the Sql command which provided by #Pekka. if you have large file say 2GB it gonna take long time untill it uploads all data to phpmysql. I have DB file with 10 GB i have found this the most helpful sql command to get the job done, however it's been two days since i've started uploading the data to my database.

Answer (score 4):

No. Use the command line client.

```
mysql -hdb.example.com -udbuser -p < fingbigquery.sql
```

Comment: ok thanks will try (hope it would use buffer as my ram is not as big as 10 Go :))